# Simulink - How to make transfer function block with just a zero

Tags: matlab, simulink

It's my first time using simulink and I just need it for a quick thing as part of a larger assignment.

I need to add a zero as part of controller for a feedback control system.
s+5

I'm trying to use the transfer function block but I can't enter just a numerator without a denominator. I tried the zero-pole block but it's giving errors too without poles. Is there just a zero block that I can use.

Here's the error

```
A time domain realization of the given zero-pole block 'untitled/Zero-Pole' failed. Check values of 'Zeros', 'Poles' and 'Gain' parameters.
```

Zeros:  [5]
Poles: [0]

[image]

Comment: A system with just a zero would be non-causal, and hence cannot be imlemented.  You either need to include a pole where the dynamics of the pole have minimal effect on the overall system, i.e. 1000*(s+5)/(s+1000), or incorporate the zero into the rest of the transfer function of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use simulink to implement just a zero;numerator and denominator must have the same degree, if this condition is not realizable the system is non-causal